# Resources to target Google Glass exclusively

Tags: android, google-glass, android-resources, google-gdk

I am developing an app that works on handheld as well as Glass. Is there any wat to provide resources exclusively to Google Glass or should I find alternatives like loading them programatically, or in the worst case, make a separate project for Glass.

As far as I know, I could use /res/values-small-land-hdpi-notouch-nokeys-v19 and the same for drawables, but I guess this would still work on phones that provide such configuration, although very unlikely.

It would be great if resource folders could target a specific combination of brand and product, something like /res/values-google-glass

Comment: There is a way, because the Google Play Music APK for Glass is the same as the one for a phone or tablet. But I'm not sure how they did this.

Comment: @hichris123 are you sure it is the same? how do you know?

Comment: [This post by one of the Glass Team](https://plus.google.com/118343182830485155505/posts/YmfHE5g6Vfb). Also, you could use it before release by sideloading the Play Store APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user experience paradigm for Google Glsss -- short interaction -- is different from the user experience paradigm for a "handheld" computer (read smartphone, tablet).  You should create two different apps (`GlassWware` and Android App) sharing the same underlying code where appropriate.

Many UX designs that are great for an app would be terrible for `Glassware`.  Look at the design guidelines for Glassware on the Google Glass developer sight.

Comment: I know, but I could provide those paradigms by routing to the proper fragment and sharing resources within the same app. That's why I'm asking